# How can we write a function to swap two enum variables?

Tags: c++, variables

How can we write a function which swap enum variables?

Also are these variables standard and working with them doesn't matter in a project?
How do C++ complier use them and put them in the RAM?

Comment: temp = e1; e1 = e2; e2 = temp; I think I need more details.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`std::swap`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/swap/):

```
enum Foo {
    CAT,
    DOG,
    ELEPHANT
};

Foo a = CAT;
Foo b = ELEPHANT;

std::swap(a, b);

std::cout << (a == ELEPHANT) << "\n";
```

`enum` is perfectly standard; they are equivalent to integer types.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to write a swap function, `std::swap` works out of the box.

`enum` is standard C++. `enum` values are represented as an integer type in memory, by default as an `int`. You can change this representation (in C++11) with, e.g.

```
enum Foo : short { A, B, C };
```

Answer (score 0):

Exactly, just use `std::swap(....)`.